# Uncaught RedisException: session_write_close()

Tags: php, redis, fpm, phpredis

So I have a website running joomla, and I tried setting the `session handler` to `redis` from CMS admin dashboard. I am getting the following error on homepage and every other page of the website I visit.

```
Error: Failed to start application: Connection closed
Fatal error: Uncaught RedisException: Connection closed in /var/www/xxxx/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php:194 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/xxxx/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php(194): session_write_close() #1 [internal function]: JSessionHandlerNative->save() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/clients/client3/web9/web/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 194
```

My server is configured with `php-fpm` as default, **Now the interesting thing is that**, if I change the php-wrapper/module to run with `Fast-CGI` (*from my server control panel*) everything **works perfect**.

Btw, I am using `PHP-Redis` as the client library, on Ubuntu, and ISPConfig as my control panel for a LAMP setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So after a lot of hair pulling, and thank God i've got these amazing goog-foo skills, here is the solution.

If you are using ISPConfig 3, and experiencing the same problem, Just do as I say below, don't ask why, **no time to explain**.

On `line 39` of the file `/usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf/php_fpm_pool.conf.master` you'll find the following template tags.

```
<tmpl_if name='custom_session_save_path' op='!=' value='y'>
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = <tmpl_var name='document_root'>/tmp
</tmpl_if>
```

Just delete it! Yeah you read that right, you gotta delete those lines man.
And after saving the changes from the admin panel, goto

`ISPConfig Admin Panel` > `Sites` > `Domain` > `PHP`

and toggle that option to disabled and let it update on the server and then set that option back to `PHP-FPM`. And....aahhh the glorious redis with the totally fab php-fpm.

**Ok, you can ask why, was kidding earlier:D**

As per [this thread](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/unable-to-set-session-save_path-when-using-php-fpm.61127/) what was happening was that joomla(*like many other CMSs*) tries to change the `session.save_path` to `redis` **during runtime** as per the settings made in admin panel of the CMS, but the "fpm-pool-template" which is shipped with ISPConfig 3 was trying to make that value editable from the Server Control panel, in the process it was making it impossible for `php` to change/overwrite that value during runtime.

As described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.apache).

> ...Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden
>   by .htaccess or ini_set().

**Now, Is it safe?** ..to remove these tags with the directives.

Its perfectly safe to remove the aforementioned lines, and those were written for the users to further modify to their needs as discussed [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/unable-to-set-session-save_path-when-using-php-fpm.61127/#post-294878). Furthermore the function used was a bit too strict (IMHO) and the same effect could have been achieved using the lesser authoritarian `php_value`.